# How to add Block Editor title word count?

Tags: wordpress

How to display the number of characters in the title of the block editor?

```
(function($) {
let countMax = 120;
$('#post-title-0').bind('keydown keyup keypress change',function(){
    let thisValueLength = $(this).val().length;
    let countDown = (countMax)-(thisValueLength);
    $('.wp-block.editor-post-title__block').after(countDown);
    console.log($countDown);
    if(countDown < 0){
        $('.wp-block.editor-post-title__block').css({color:'#ff0000',fontWeight:'bold'});
    } else {
        $('.wp-block.editor-post-title__block').css({color:'#000000',fontWeight:'normal'});
    }
});
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.wp-block.editor-post-title__block').after(countMax);
});
}(jQuery));
```

But not work.

Comment: is `$('.character-count')` part of the HTML?

Comment: mistake. class fixed.